# can you replace Tektro M280 pad adjuster bolt only?

Tags: brakes

I totally stripped the adjuster bolt on my rear caliper, it had a hex head, now it's round and doesn't turn anymore. Do you know if it's possible to replace the pad adjuster bolt only without replacing the entire caliper?
I couldn't find that part online.

[image: tektro pad adjuster]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can extract that bolt and measure it, then identifying a replacement would be easier.

However when I tried to remove an adjuster from a different brand of caliper, it was locked in during manufacturing and couldn't be disassembled without unbending some retainer clips.

In the end I upgraded from a mechanical caliper to a low-end shimano hydraulic for relatively low cost.

---

Another temporary fix might be to use a hacksaw or dremel to cut a slot across the whole bolthead, and use a very large flathead screwdriver to adjust the bolt position.  It's up to you whether this is acceptable.

---

Do consider this is part of your braking system, which is an area where function is critical and compromise can have consequences.

Consider an all-new replacement caliper if the bolt doesn't come out easily.

---

**Update** there's no chance you're going to find a replacement in a hardware store because its not a bolt; instead it is some kind of pancake head.

I expect it also has 2 or more spring-loaded ball bearings on the sides that push out into those recesses.

On the positive side, if you can grab the current one, it should come out without damage.  Perhaps use an oversized torx bit and hammer into the hole as a sacrificial driver.

[image]

Comment: Considering how critical it is and cheap to replace I don't think any diy work will be worth it. It was expected since I couldn't find it any replacement part.

Comment: @SandroAntonucci  I went for the lowest spec shimano hydraulic pre-bled brake and lever combo.  It was dead simple to install, superior braking and both sides move rather than being a single sided brake.   Highly recommended especially for the price.  I think it was MT-200 set.

Comment: the only issue is that I have a hub motor and I would like to keep the motor cut off system

Comment: @SandroAntonucci Oh okay that's an added wrinkle.  Changing lever will loose the sensor/switch that controls motor cutoff.   It may be possible to replace this brake with hydraulic and leave the other brake as mechanical, but this is getting outside my knowledge.  Googling suggests there are hydraulic levers with cutoff switches, and there are also inline-sensors that do the same job, eg https://www.converted.co.nz/product/brake-cut-off-sensor-hydraulic/  but I can't speak with experience.

Comment: On both the similar designs I've dealt with, the adjuster screw was retained by a plastic clip that also acted as an adjusting knob until it failed. That came off quite easily, allowing access to the real metal adjuster, which could then be backed out

Comment: BTW the thread looks to be something like M20x1, and it's effectively a grubscrew. Bet much a custom part

Comment: @SandroAntonucci having ridden an ebike with a failed cutoff switch, I don't recommend it (the manufacturer tethered the cable too tidily, so using the brake lever's barrel adjuster strained the plastic switch body until it broke, leaving the switch dangling). That was probably the same brake as you've got, but I haven't seen that bike for a few years now

Comment: I'll replace the caliper :)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like another BB5 copy (or almost, as it uses different pads). I've failed to find replacements for Promax's BB5 clone or Avid's original - but the thread is the same on both of those.

Stripping the head of this part seems like a common failure mode - they're aluminium and prone to binding and getting mucky. If you got a replacement (whether Tektro or one of the brands I mentioned) a little anti seize grease on the threads is a good idea. I clean and regrease mine when I change pads at home.

The fact that they're made of aluminium also means the trick of cutting a slot for a screwdriver is easy - but you're quite likely to tear it with the screwdriver. I suggest taking the pads out and applying penetrating oil (chain oil will do if you don't have anything lighter, but wait a few hours with the bike lying so gravity pulls it in).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a reddit user I was able to find the part, I haven't purchased it since I replaced the caliper already but it is possible. This is the link https://tektro-usa.com/product/md-m280-pad-adjuster-spring-and-ball-bearing/